# deleting few of the git commits so that they do not appear in the logs

Tags: git, git-rebase

```
* 6a2da68        (styleChange) merge fix in setting
* dac420f        added libs
* 622021c        merging changes
| * 18847ab      (production/master, master) added couple of cdns
| * 8f02c19      minified css files
| * 276649a      (HEAD, testminify) added libs
| * f4b9533      fixed fb
|/  
* 2b4b490        prod ready
* 685a99c        removed dj static from settings file
* 1f012bc        added mailing support
* eb69d26        modified wsgi and static files
* bbd5c76        settings
* 39b229b        deleted some files
* 7e8ecaa        Initial Commit
```

As you can see above my head is on, 276649a (*added libs* commit) 
as of now I want to get rid of all the commits ahead of the commit where head is, so that finally my git graph looks as follows -

```
* 276649a        (HEAD, testminify) added libs
* f4b9533        fixed fb
* 2b4b490        prod ready
* 685a99c        removed dj static from settings file
* 1f012bc        added mailing support
* eb69d26        modified wsgi and static files
* bbd5c76        settings
* 39b229b        deleted some files
* 7e8ecaa        Initial Commit
```

Is there any way I can prettify my git branch tree?
So basically I want to get rid of the redundant future branches and couple of commits as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the commits you don’t want to appear are on separate branches, it is enough if you just remove those branches:

```
git branch -D styleChange
git branch -D master
```

Comment: doing the above brings to the following stage -                                            `* 18847ab        (production/master) added couple of cdns
* 8f02c19        minified css files
* 276649a        (HEAD, testminify) added libs
* f4b9533        fixed fb
* 2b4b490        prod ready
* 685a99c        removed dj static from settings file
* 1f012bc        added mailing support
* eb69d26        modified wsgi and static files
* bbd5c76        settings
* 39b229b        deleted some files
* 7e8ecaa        Initial Commit`

Comment: `master` still exists on the `production` remote, that’s why it still appears. You could delete it on the remote too: `git push production :master`

Answer (score 0):

Detach head then move master to

```
git checkout 276649a
git branch -f master HEAD
```